# Checking one row against the next in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with three columns (`id`, `date_start` and `date_end`) and `id` is not unique. I want to check that, for all `id`, whenever there a new `start_date`, the previous `start_date`'s `end_date` always occurs before the new `start_date`. I'm thinking of joining the table on itself trying to add a column with the `start_date` (if there are any) so that I can check this against `end_date` but I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I'm running SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this as a self join.  I think the clearer expression is using a correlated subquery.  The following query returns all exceptions, according to your rule:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.end_date
              from table t2
              where t2.start_date < t.start_date
              order by t2.start_date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_end_date
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_end_date >= start_date;
```